# Regex to find Base64 in raw body of email (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, regex, email, base64

Okay, so I'm trying to find a Base64 image in an email string using regex.

The last two lines of that particular Base64 string looks like this:

```
ublR+iVp4k0KLTdJt7jULC0uIrZY3UkJuYZ56859aK+Ftc1H4ja5ei+0a2s49M2BIt+CSBnuQc0V
6tLIrxTsdiZ//9k=
```

Okay, so here's my regex

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\//n]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4})$
```

And broken down for my own sanity

`^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/\n]{4})` the beginning of the string should have four characters (being those which are Base64 valid, and new lines)

`*` That should occur least once, but probably loads of times

`(...)$` At the end of the string ...

`[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}==` gimme two characters and two buffers

`|` or ...

`[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=` three characters and one buffer

`|` or ...

`[A-Za-z0-9+\/]` four characters like before

---

So

When I run

`/^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/\n]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+\/\n]{4})$/.match(email.raw_body)`

It only matches up to the end of the penultimate line.

However

When I run

`/^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/\n]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=)$/.match(email.raw_body)`

it does work.

So it seems to be that last or `|` statement which seems a bit flawed.

Can anyone offer a kind suggestion? It would very much help a rapidly ageing man. :-)

Comment: Aren't there boundary/content markers for the encoded block? If it's a MIME message there should be. Have you tried using the pre-built gems for this?

Comment: Have you tried a [*simple search*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex+base64?sort=votes&pageSize=50) on SO ?

Comment: Hey @theTinMan - yes there are boundary markers. I am using [Griddler by Thoughtbot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler) to process the emails, but sometimes attachments aren't attachments - they're inline images. [As you can read,](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler/issues/104) I struggled with Griddler, too. This has been fun.

Comment: @HamZa - yep, I try everything I can within the limits of my time and patience (which is about a week). I hate posting on SO because (1) I'm admitting defeat and (2) you tend to get a sarcastic answer.

Comment: You shouldn't get sarcastic answers on SO. People answering are supposed to be here to help, though, when a question is very poorly written and shows little effort, it is frustrating to waste time trying to dig out the needed, essential, information to make a useful answer, which is when frustration starts to creep in and sarcasm comes out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use regex

```
input.match /^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4}\n?)*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=)?$/
```

See **[this demo](http://ideone.com/C5NP6e)**.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was confused at first, as your demo clearly works, but it wasn't working when I processed the email - it was matching `""`. But changing `*` to `+` to force at least one match seems to do the trick. Thank you.